# Sink is full when calling rmarkdown::render

Tags: r, r-markdown, sink

I'm following [this short tutorial](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/render-reports-directly-from-R-scripts/) to print my R script directly as an HTML document. It should be pretty straightforward. With a few small changes to the header and comments of an otherwise normal R script, calling the command
`rmarkdown::render('/Users/you/Documents/yourscript.R')` at the end of an R script should call the `knitr::spin` function to go from my R script to an Rmd file to the final HTML or PDF.

I'm getting the error:
`Error in sink(con, split = debug) : sink stack is full` and I'm not sure what to do. All solutions I've found online point out that one needs to close sink()'s after opening them. But since I'm not really using `sink()` myself, I don't see how or where I should close them.

I'm using R 3.3.0.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134313/r-markdown-rendering-sink-stack-is-full-calls-error) Question asks the same but is downvoted and has no answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it turned out I was doing something stupid: I included the command `rmarkdown::render('/Users/you/Documents/yourscript.R')` within my script and forgot to comment it out. I probably ended doing an infinite recursion. I commented that line out and it worked beautifully.

Comment: FYI, if you want to include the `rmarkdown::render()` command in a chunk in the doc itself so you can easily run it and knit to all formats, just put the chunk option `eval=FALSE` in the chunk header. This way it won't recursively run that command when knitting the doc itself.